# Inline assembly causes Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: x86, simd, inline-assembly, intrinsics, avx

I'm attempting to convert the Intel intrinsics into inline assembly.

The code is going to calculate a 4x4 Matrix. The size of `A` and `B` are `4 x kc` and `kc x 4`, respectively.

Here is the complete function:

```c
 #define MR 4
 #define NR 4
 // compute C := beta * C + alpha * AB
 static void  dgemm_micro_kernel(int kc,
               double alpha, const double *A, const double *B,
               double beta,
               double *C, int incRowC, int incColC)
{ 
    double AB[MR*NR] __attribute__ ((aligned (32)));

    int i, j, p;
    register __m256d ab_00_10_20_30, ab_01_11_21_31, ab_02_12_22_32, ab_03_13_23_33;
    register __m256d a_0123, b_0000, b_1111, b_2222, b_3333;


    ab_00_10_20_30 = _mm256_setzero_pd();
    ab_01_11_21_31 = _mm256_setzero_pd();
    ab_02_12_22_32 = _mm256_setzero_pd();
    ab_03_13_23_33 = _mm256_setzero_pd();

    for (p = 0; p < kc; p++)
    {
        a_0123 = _mm256_load_pd(A);
        b_0000 = _mm256_broadcast_sd(B);
        b_1111 = _mm256_broadcast_sd(B + 1);
        b_2222 = _mm256_broadcast_sd(B + 2);
        b_3333 = _mm256_broadcast_sd(B + 3);

        // Col 1
        ab_00_10_20_30 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(a_0123, b_0000, ab_00_10_20_30);
        // Col 2
        ab_01_11_21_31 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(a_0123, b_1111, ab_01_11_21_31);
        // Col 3
        ab_02_12_22_32 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(a_0123, b_2222, ab_02_12_22_32);
        // Col 4
        ab_03_13_23_33 = _mm256_fmadd_pd(a_0123, b_3333, ab_03_13_23_33);

        A += MR;
        B += NR;
  }
    _mm256_store_pd(AB +  0, ab_00_10_20_30);
    _mm256_store_pd(AB +  4, ab_01_11_21_31);
    _mm256_store_pd(AB +  8, ab_02_12_22_32);
    _mm256_store_pd(AB + 12, ab_03_13_23_33);

    // Updata C := beta * C
    if (beta == 0.0)
   {
        // C == 0
        for (j = 0; j < NR; j++)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < MR; i++)
           {
                C[i * incRowC + j * incColC] = 0.0;
          }
      }
    }
    else if (beta != 1.0)
    {
        // C := beta * C
        for (j = 0; j < NR; j++)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < MR; i++)
            {
                C[i * incRowC + j * incColC] *= beta;
            }
        }
    }

    // Updata C := C + alpha * AB
    if (alpha == 1.0)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < NR; j++)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < MR; i++)
            {
                C[i * incRowC + j * incColC] += AB[j * MR + i];
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (j = 0; j < NR; j++)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < MR; i++)
            {
                C[i * incRowC + j * incColC] += alpha * AB[j * MR + i];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my inline assembly (just post the related part):

```
double AB[16] __attribute__ ((aligned(32)));
__asm__ volatile
(
    "movl           %0,         %%esi               \n\t"   // kc
    "movq           %1,         %%rax               \n\t"   // A
    "movq           %2,         %%rbx               \n\t"   // B
    "movq           %3,         %%rcx               \n\t"   // AB
    "                                               \n\t"
    "vxorpd         %%ymm0,     %%ymm0,     %%ymm0  \n\t"   // SET ZERO
    "vxorpd         %%ymm1,     %%ymm1,     %%ymm1  \n\t"
    "vxorpd         %%ymm2,     %%ymm2,     %%ymm2  \n\t"
    "vxorpd         %%ymm3,     %%ymm3,     %%ymm3  \n\t"
    "                                               \n\t"
    "testl           %%esi,      %%esi               \n\t"   // CHECK
    "je             .DWRITEAB                       \n\t"
    "                                               \n\t"
    ".DLOOP:                                        \n\t"   // LOOP
    "vmovapd        (%%rax),    %%ymm4              \n\t"   // load a_0123
    "vbroadcastsd   (%%rbx),    %%ymm5              \n\t"   // load b_0000
    "vbroadcastsd   8(%%rbx),   %%ymm6              \n\t"   // load b_1111
    "vbroadcastsd   16(%%rbx),  %%ymm7              \n\t"   // load b_2222
    "vbroadcastsd   24(%%rbx),  %%ymm8              \n\t"   // load b_3333
    "                                               \n\t"
    "vfmadd132pd    %%ymm4,     %%ymm5,     %%ymm0  \n\t"   // Col 1
    "vfmadd132pd    %%ymm4,     %%ymm6,     %%ymm1  \n\t"   // Col 2
    "vfmadd132pd    %%ymm4,     %%ymm7,     %%ymm2  \n\t"   // Col 3
    "vfmadd132pd    %%ymm4,     %%ymm8,     %%ymm3  \n\t"   // Col 4
    "                                               \n\t"
    "addq           $32,        %%rax               \n\t"
    "addq           $32,        %%rbx               \n\t"
    "                                               \n\t"
    "decl           %%esi                           \n\t"
    "jne            .DLOOP                          \n\t"
    "                                               \n\t"
    ".DWRITEAB:                                     \n\t"
    "vmovapd        %%ymm0,     (%%rcx)             \n\t"
    "vmovapd        %%ymm1,     32(%%rcx)           \n\t"
    "vmovapd        %%ymm2,     64(%%rcx)           \n\t"
    "vmovapd        %%ymm3,     96(%%rcx)           \n\t"
    "                                               \n\t"
    : // output
    : // input
        "m" (kc), // 0
        "m" (A),  // 1
        "m" (B),  // 2
        "m" (AB) // 3
    : // clober list
        "rax", "rbx", "rcx", "esi",
        "xmm0", "xmm1", "xmm2", "xmm3", "xmm4",
        "xmm5", "xmm6", "xmm7", "xmm8", "memory"
);
```

Then I compile and run it, the output shows `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. However, the intrinsic version works well. What's wrong with my inline assembly code?

Comment: Could you just post both functions completely? Does the first function actually write back to `C`?

Comment: @chtz I already posted the complete function. I only modified the intrinsics part of whole function.

Comment: Your snippet is still not complete, e.g., it misses the definition of `MR` and `NR`. Read how (and why) to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @chtz sorry, i forgot them. Already edited.

Comment: I'm not clear why you aren't running this under the debugger to figure out precisely where the crash is coming from.  If that's not possible, I'd start by trimming out the vmovapd at DWRITEAB. Yes you'd get the wrong answer, but if it doesn't crash, you'd know where to look.  Also, I see you are clobbering xmm*, but using ymm*.  Given the relationship between the two this might work, but I might try changing (or just adding) the ymm* registers.

Answer (score 2):

`AB` is an array, but you are using it as a pointer.
Also, it is an output, but it is listed as an input.

The easiest change to fix this is to use `lea` instead of `mov` to load the address of `AB` into `rcx`. Also put `"=m"(AB)` as an output.

A better solution is to let the compiler do register allocation and remove the clobbers for eax, ebx, ecx, and esi. By using an `"r"` constraint, the compiler converts the array to a pointer to its first element and puts the pointer in the register. You can avoid the memory clobber by listing the array operands twice.

WARNING, this isn’t quite right, because it doesn’t properly indicate that the assembly code changes its input registers. Since you haven’t shown the entire function, I can’t tell if that will cause a problem (but it’s definitely wrong).

```
asm ("..."
    : // output
      "=m"(AB)
    : // input
      "r"(kc), "r"(A), "r"(B), "r"(AB),
      "m"(*(double (*)[4*kc])A), "m"(*(double (*)[4*kc])B)
    : // clobber list
      "xmm0", "xmm1", "xmm2", "xmm3", "xmm4",
      "xmm5", "xmm6", "xmm7", "xmm8"
);
```

This requires changing all the references to the parameters in the assembly code to use `%1`, `%2`, `%3`, and `%4`.

Comment: I add some infomation about the function. `AB` is a local variable.

Comment: Ah, so A and B are pointers, only AB is an array. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I modified the code but the result is still `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Comment: I'll be happy to look at your updated code if you add it to the question (or ask a new question).